# "On the house" as in offered free of charge

Tags: traduction, expressions

How do we translate “on the house” with the meaning of something offered free of charge, for example “the drink/dish is on the house”.

How about “this meal/drink is on me” meaning I will pay for it . Perhaps some other translation rather than the usual “je t'invite”? What would “ce repas, c'est à moi” mean? I have the feeling that this is not the translation, but mean more of “it belongs to me”.

Comment: [Reverso context](http://context.reverso.net/traduction/anglais-francais/it's+on+the+house) is a good place to look for translations. Your are right *c'est à moi*  would not be appropriate here. *C'est la maison qui offre* or *c'est offert par la maison* are the closest to what you want.  *Je t'invite* would only be appropriate if "je" is the owner of the place.

Comment: _Je t'invite_ would only be appropriate if "je" is the owner of the place. That's surprising to me because my French friend always say so when he offers paying for the resto. _C'est moi qui paie_, _Je t'invite_ are what used.

Comment: We're saying the same thing.  If you're friend is paying, *je t'invite* is perfectly appropriate, but "It's on the house" is also  what the manager  says if the place is offering the drink,  *c'est la maison*  is more appropriate in that case.

Comment: "Aux frais de la princesse" peut également être utilisé en fonction du contexte, ou par exemple, la personne rentre ça dans des notes de frais (dîner d'affaires, etc.)

Comment: *It's on me* can be translated as *c'est pour moi*, refering to the tab, usually used at the moment of paying.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Other ways to say "It's on the house":

- *C'est offert (par la maison)* (This is what I hear most)
- *C'est la tournée du patron*
- *C'est aux frais du patron / de la maison*

Comment: I've also heard "Compliment de la maison"

Comment: Yes, but plural: *(avec les) compliments de la maison*

Comment: tu vois, je n'etais pas certain et j'ai corrige ma phrase en enlevant le pluriel. Je voyais "avec les compliments de la maison", mais je me disais que selon le contexte, ca aurait aussi pu etre "(ce verre est un) Compliment de la maison". Merci de la correction (et desole pour le manque d'accents.... clavier anglais :P)

Comment: personnellement, je ne comprend pas "avec les compliments de la maison" dans ce sens. Cela ne signifie pas que c'est "offert" ([source](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/compliment/17709)), c'est juste une formule de politesse...

Comment: Plus formel et à réserver à certains usages : "A titre gracieux"

Answer (score 8):

You have multiple ways to say it in french, the most common are :

> C'est [la maison / moi] qui [offre / régale]
>   C'est pour [moi / bibi]
>   C'est [cadeau / offert]

Answer (score 0):

I would say in French, « compliments de l'entreprise »
when it is on the expense of the house (a gift)

Comment: We don't say that in French, *compliments* can't be used in that way.